# python running sql select with var does not work

Tags: python, mysql

I have spent at least 2 hours on this

```
    self.ac=14786894668
    myCode = str(self.ac)

    query = """select * from myTable where AC_CD = '%s' """ % (myCode)
    print(query)
    res = self.mycursor.execute(query)
    print(res)
    for row in self.mycursor.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

#

does not give me the DB result

print(query) gives me -->

```
select * from myTable where AC_CD = '14786894668'
```

print(res) gives me --> pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x04F3E6A0

which is correct and I copy and paste the exact result from print(query) -->

```
select * from myTable where AC_CD = '14786894668'
```

in my UI DB and it works and I see the rows and all data

I should note that this code does not give me any rows:

```
    for row in self.mycursor.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

Comment: So you say print(query) and print(res) are giving you correct results, so where are you seeing the issue that's not working?

Comment: when I run this code I dont see the results   of rows         columns = [column[0] for column in self.mycursor.description]
        print("columns: " + "\n" + str(columns))
        self.queryResults = []
        for row in self.mycursor.fetchall():
            self.queryResults.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

Comment: or when I run   -->    
    for row in self.mycursor.fetchall():
        print(row)   I dont see any rows

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the problem and of course kick myself for wasting so much time.

The AC_CD was generated in QA environment my python code was executing the Query it in Staging DB.  and of course it couldn't find it.